# Filter google markers with knockout

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js

I've been trying to solve this issues with no luck. I already check other posts and no luck. I think I have an error on my code, my goal is to be able to filter the list and show/hide only the markers on that list. A sample of the code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/rp2t3gyn/2/

Here is a sample of the code that is not working for some reason:

```
self.filteredPlaces = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.placeList(), function (placeItem) {
        placeItem.marker.setVisible(true);
      });
      return self.placeList();
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.placeList(), function(placeItem) {
        // set all markers visible (false)
        var result = (placeItem.city.toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);
        placeItem.marker.setVisible(result);
        return result;
      });
    }
  }, this);
```

Thanks

Comment: The error is being thrown because there is no `marker` property in `placeItem`

Comment: How can i give those properties to 'placeItem'

Comment: There is a javascript error in your fiddle: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter the markers you need to do a few things.

Your first problem is this line:

```
    placeItem.marker.setVisible(true);
```

Place item doesn't have a marker object based on your constructor. So, you have to add it. I changed the Place constructor to add a marker object (see below).

```
var Place = function(data, map, viewmodel) {
this.city = data.city;
this.lat = data.lat;
this.lng = data.lng;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: {lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng},
  city: data.city,
  icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5
      },
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
});
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    viewmodel.clickSelection(marker, viewmodel.largeInfoWindow);
});
this.marker = marker;
```

};

and used that to initialize your objects. Lastly, I changed your filteredPlaces function, it needs to subscribe to the query observable so that when you type in text the markers on the map adjust accordingly .

```
   self.query.subscribe(function() {
    var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.placeList(), function (placeItem) {
                placeItem.marker.setMap(map);
            });
            return self.placeList();
        } else {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.placeList(), function(placeItem) {
                var result = (placeItem.city.toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);

                if(result)
                    placeItem.marker.setMap(map);
                else
                    placeItem.marker.setMap(null);
            });
        }
    });
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/rp2t3gyn/3/)